# How to change computed object in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs, vuex

I have simple select of months:

```
<select v-model="month" v-on:change="dateChanged('month', month)">
    <option v-for="(month, index) in months" :value="index">{{ month }}</option>
</select>
```

The main date object stored in Vuex:

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['date']), 
    month() {
        return this.date.format('M') - 1
    },
```

The problem is that when I change months the `month` value doesn't change... Visually month in select changed but the value is still the same as it was before.

Comment: You might wanna take a look at  **Two-way Computed Property** in
 https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/forms.html .  v-model is for local state. your month state is in Vuex. `v-model="month"` won't work unless you only want to change local state and not Vuex state

Answer (score 1):

That's because a `computed` property, as the name suggests, can only be overwritten internally and it's not a data store that you can write to. If you want to populate your `month` from the VueX store and retain writability, it is best written as a combination of:

- a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) that watches `date`, and updates the internal `month` data whenever the store is updated
- a internal data that simply allows writing and reading of `month`

An example is as follow:

```
// Populate internal store with state data
data: function() {
    return {
        month: this.date.format('M') - 1
    }
},

// Map getter
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['date'])
},

// Watch changes to mapped getter
watch: {
    date: function(val) {
        this.month = this.date.format('M') - 1
    }
}
```

Of course, following the DRY principle, you might want to abstract the logic into a separate method:

```
methods: {
    getMonth: function(month) {
        return month.format('M') - 1;
    }   
},
data: function() {
    return {
        month: this.getMonth(this.date)
    }
},
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['date'])
},
watch: {
    date: function(val) {
        this.month = this.getMonth(val)
    }
}
```